# Generate password in Python

Tags: python, passwords

I'd like to generate some alphanumeric passwords in Python. Some possible ways are:

```
import string
from random import sample, choice
chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
length = 8
''.join(sample(chars, length))                 # first way
''.join(choice(chars) for i in range(length))  # second way
```

But I don't the first way because only unique chars are selected and you can't generate passwords where `length > len(chars)` and I don't like the second way because we have an unused `i` variable. Are there any other good options?

Comment: There's nothing really wrong with the second option. Is it *too* slow? Do you need it to be faster? Are you running out of memory?

Comment: Unused 'i' bother my mind and IDE. ;)

Comment: use `_` instead.

Comment: Just quick FYI, the draft [PEP 0506 -- Adding A Secrets Module To The Standard Library](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0506/) just came out and it specifically links to this question and an answer.

Comment: you should NOT use the `random` module, it's pseudo-randomness is fine for testing but INCREDIBLY weak for this purpose.  Use the built-in `secrets` module instead

Answer (score 239, accepted):

On Python **3.6**+ you should use the [secrets module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html) to generate cryptographically safe passwords. Adapted from the documentation:

```
import secrets
import string
alphabet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
password = ''.join(secrets.choice(alphabet) for i in range(20))  # for a 20-character password
```

For more information on recipes and best practices, see [this section on recipes in the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#recipes-and-best-practices).  You can also consider adding [`string.punctuation`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.punctuation).

Comment: if you decide to add `string.punctuation`, I would recommend to slice out `\' backslash which is the 23rd character as it can be confusing.

Comment: @JiWei Is it? As long as the character is available on all common keyboards and not easily [confusable](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/confusables.jsp), it would seem that it's fine in a password. Anyway, removing one character from a sufficiently long password is not going to break security (I personally avoid I, 1, O, 0 in any passwords I have to type manually).

Comment: @gerrit: It could confuse an amateur like me. :D I used your code snippet to generate a password to password-protect an Excel file, and at the same time printed the password to stdout (I use Powershell and Notepad++). I realized that whenever there are 2 backslashes, somehow the password cannot be used to unprotect the Excel file. Turns out it should be read as one backslash because the first backslash is an escape character.

Answer (score 38):

For the crypto-PRNG folks out there:

```
def generate_temp_password(length):
    if not isinstance(length, int) or length < 8:
        raise ValueError("temp password must have positive length")

    chars = "ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ23456789"
    from os import urandom

    # original Python 2 (urandom returns str)
    # return "".join(chars[ord(c) % len(chars)] for c in urandom(length))

    # Python 3 (urandom returns bytes)
    return "".join(chars[c % len(chars)] for c in urandom(length))
```

Note that for an even distribution, the `chars` string length ought to be an integral divisor of 128; otherwise, you'll need a different way to choose uniformly from the space.

Comment: You can eliminate the list in the last line via a generator expression: `return "".join(chars[ord(c) % len(chars)] for c in urandom(length))`

Comment: This is the best answer, but you should clearify the answer so that anyone finding this via Google understands why it's the best one.

Comment: crypto-PRNG stands for "cryptograhically-secure Pseudorandom number generator".  This answer is one of the best because it generates secure passwords. The default pseudorandom number generator in the `random` module is not secure.

Comment: FWIW, after years of service, this code generated an obscene password. here is another post about the perils of alphanumeric password/id generation: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/143405/32537

Comment: ```TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found``` I am getting this error when running this code, don't know why people are saying this is good.

Comment: @VinayKumarShukla good catch, this was written originally for Python 2. added a Python 3 version.

Answer (score 33):

Two recipes using the builtin [secrets](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/secrets.html) (python 3.6+)

#### 1. secrets.token_urlsafe

This is *much* faster than the accepted answer. (see timings below)

```py
import secrets
password = secrets.token_urlsafe(32)
```

Example output:

```
4EPn9Z7RE3l6jtCxEy7CPhia2EnYDEkE6N1O3-WnntU
```

The argument for `token_urlsafe` is number of bytes. On average, one byte is 1.3 characters (base64 encoded).

#### 2. Enforce amount of digits/upper characters etc

This is slighly modified copy from the docs of secrets. With this you have more fine grained control on how to generated passwords have to look. Of course, this is not *fast* option if you need to generate a *lot* of passwords.

- Forcing length to be 20 characters
- Forcing at least 4 lower case character
- Forcing at least 4 upper case characters
- Forcing at least 4 digits
- Special characters can be added to `alphabet`. In this example, there are just `-` and `_` added.

```py
import string
import secrets
alphabet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '-_'
while True:
    password = ''.join(secrets.choice(alphabet) for i in range(20))
    if (sum(c.islower() for c in password) >=4
            and sum(c.isupper() for c in password) >=4
            and sum(c.isdigit() for c in password) >=4):
        break
```

Example output:

```
HlxTm2fcFE54JA1I_Yp5
```

#### 3. "I don't need the finer-grained control"

If considered speed, you can also drop the while-loop. In this case, it actually simplifies to gerrit's answer (but then you loose the finer-grained control):

```py
import string
import secrets
alphabet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '-_'
password = ''.join(secrets.choice(alphabet) for i in range(20))
```

### Speed comparison

**1. secrets.token_urlsafe**

```
1.62 µs ± 96.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

**2. Enforce amount of digits/upper characters etc**

```
107 µs ± 11.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

**3. "I don't need the finer-grained control"**

```
77.2 µs ± 9.31 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

<sup>Speed comparison setup: python 3.8.5 64-bit on Win10, 43 characters in each password (=32 bytes for token_urlsafe).</sup>

Answer (score 12):

**WARNING** this answer should be ignored due to critical security issues!

Option #2 seems quite reasonable except you could add a couple of improvements:

```
''.join(choice(chars) for _ in range(length))          # in py2k use xrange
```

`_` is a conventional "I don't care what is in there" variable. And you don't need list comprehension there, generator expression works just fine for `str.join`. It is also not clear what "slow" means, if it is the only *correct* way.

Comment: You should use secure random number generators for password generation or your passwords may be easily compromised.  The default python RNG is not a secure one.  "Python uses the Mersenne Twister as the core generator. ... The Mersenne Twister ... is completely unsuitable for cryptographic purposes." -http://docs.python.org/library/random.html

Comment: I would like to backup Fasaxc on this. Please look at @livibetter's comment, use the [secrets](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/secrets.html) module from [PEP0506](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0506/). As livibetter stated, this article is referenced as a bad example. I know this is an old question that I am commenting on, but it's still one of the top search results. I'd recommend someone change the accepted answer to gerrit's.

Answer (score 6):

I think this'll do the trick. `random.SystemRandom` uses the same underlying crypto random function as `os.urandom` but it uses the familiar `random` interface.  This function won't be subject to the weird 128 byte thing as in Ben's answer.

```
import random
import string

def gen_random_string(char_set, length):
    if not hasattr(gen_random_string, "rng"):
        gen_random_string.rng = random.SystemRandom() # Create a static variable
    return ''.join([ gen_random_string.rng.choice(char_set) for _ in xrange(length) ])

password_charset = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
gen_random_string(password_charset, 32)
```

Comment: Why would you want to set `rng` as an attribute?

Comment: This is so you don't have to initialize `random.SystemRandom()` each time.

Comment: One thing to note, this solution isn't any less secure (in the current version of python) than the accepted version that uses `secrets.choice`.  `secrets.choice` is an alias of `random.SystemRandom().choice`, although I would recommend the secrets module for newer programs.  (This post was created when python 2 was still a thing and the secrets module wasn't universally available).

Answer (score 4):

I suggest the following for those stuck on python <3.6:

```
import os, math, string, struct

def generate_password(pass_len):
    symbols = string.printable.strip()
    return ''.join([symbols[x * len(symbols) / 256] for x in struct.unpack('%dB' % (pass_len,), os.urandom(pass_len))])
```

This has the advantage over Ben Mosher's solution that the each symbol from symbols has an equal change of occurring whereas using modulus slightly favors the first symbols in the alpabet. The alphabet of symbols is also larger in this suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

What I once did while using [PyCryptodome](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/features.html) module was this:

```
from Cryptodome.Random import get_random_bytes
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode

def get_password(lenght):
    return b64encode(get_random_bytes(lenght)).decode('utf-8')

password = get_password(21)
```

You decide how long you want the password to be at "get_random_bytes(lenght)".

Comment: lenght <> length

Answer (score -1):

You can use random and chr with symbols from 33 to 127:

```
from random import randint

symb_count = int(input('Enter count of symbols:'))
passwd = []
while len(passwd) < symb_count:
    passwd.append(chr(randint(33, 127)))
print(''.join(passwd))
```

Comment: This is insecure

Answer (score -1):

## Yet another one-liner:

```
python -c "import random;print(''.join([random.choice(random.choice([['a','e','f','g','h','m','n','t','y'],['A','B','E','F','G','H','J','K','L','M','N','Q','R','T','X','Y'],['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'],['/','*','+','~','@','#','%','^','&','//']])) for i in range(16)]));"
```

### Samples:

L+f##Q~H88NBe6Ny

&7@M7gt4J^///gH3e

5e2455hgn2h^//ffh

### Advantage:

Change char list **explicitly**, exclude similar chars(etc. i 1 l I, 0 o O).(Just add/del in the list)

Change password length from **16** to whatever you want.

### Disadvantage:

Readability.

PS. readable version:

```
python -c "import random;\
print(''.join([random.choice(random.choice(\
[\
 ['a','e','f','g','h','m','n','t','y'],\
 ['A','B','E','F','G','H','J','K','L','M','N','Q','R','T','X','Y'],\
 ['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'],\
 ['/','*','+','~','@','#','%','^','&','//']\
])) \
for i in range(16)]));"
```

Comment: This is insecure

Answer (score -3):

Here in the line 9 of above coding:

```
return (choice(options) for _ in xrange(length))
```

Actually the `xrange` is not defined, so the correct coding for this is:

```
return (choice(options) for _ in range(length))
```

Same in 76 line too.

Comment: Should this be a comment to some answer?

Comment: this is insecure

Answer (score -5):

I wrote a [script](http://bitbucket.org/kniht/scraps/src/104d8782bb83/python/newpass.py) with my preferences, which mostly are concerned with avoiding mistakes when transcribing and remembering.  (For example: remove somewhat ambiguous and no repeated characters.)

```
import optparse
import os
import random
import sys

DEFAULT_CHARS = "234679ADEFGHJKLMNPRTUWabdefghijkmnpqrstuwy"
DEFAULT_LEN = 18

def choices(options, length, choice=random.choice):
  return (choice(options) for _ in xrange(length))

def choices_non_repeated(options, length, choice=random.choice):
  assert len(options) > 1
  last = choice(options)
  count = 0
  while count < length:
    yield last
    count += 1

    while True:
      value = choice(options)
      if value != last:
        last = value
        break

def main(args):
  op = optparse.OptionParser(add_help_option=False)
  op.add_option("--help", action="help",
    help="show help message and exit")
  op.add_option("-b", "--bare", action="store_true", default=False,
    help="print passwords without trailing newline")
  op.add_option("-c", "--chars", metavar="SET", nargs=1, default=DEFAULT_CHARS,
    help="character set to use (default: %default)")
  op.add_option("--repeat", action="store_true", default=False,
    help="allow repetition")
  op.add_option("-l", "--len", dest="max", nargs=1, type="int", default=DEFAULT_LEN,
    help="max length (default: %default)")
  op.add_option("--min", nargs=1, type="int", default=None,
    help="min length (defaults to max)")
  op.add_option("-n", "--count", nargs=1, type="int", default=None,
    help="number of passwords to generate (default: %default)")
  op.add_option("--cols", type="int", default=None,
    help="number of columns to use")
  opts, args = op.parse_args(args)
  if args:
    op.error("unknown arguments")

  if os.isatty(sys.stdin.fileno()) and (
    opts.count is None and opts.cols is None
    and not opts.bare
  ):
    opts.cols = 80 // (opts.max + 1)
    opts.count = opts.cols * 25
  else:
    if opts.count is None:
      opts.count = 1
    if opts.cols is None:
      opts.cols = 1

  if opts.bare and opts.cols != 1:
    op.error("bare output requires --cols=1")

  if opts.min == None:
    opts.min = opts.max

  if any(x < 1 for x in [opts.cols, opts.count, opts.min, opts.max]):
    op.error("values must be >= 1")

  choices_func = choices_non_repeated
  if opts.repeat:
    choices_func = choices
  elif len(set(opts.chars)) < 2:
    op.error("must allow repetition or provide a longer character set")
    return "op.error shouldn't return"

  col = 0
  for _ in xrange(opts.count):
    length = random.randint(opts.min, opts.max)
    password = "".join(choices_func(opts.chars, length))
    sys.stdout.write(password)
    if not opts.bare:
      col += 1
      if col == opts.cols:
        sys.stdout.write("\n")
        col = 0
      else:
        sys.stdout.write(" ")


if __name__ == "__main__":
  sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
```

Comment: this is likely insecure

Answer (score -5):

You may want to use `map` instead of list comprehensions:

```
''.join(map(lambda x: random.choice(chars), range(length)))
```

Comment: this is insecure