# How to generate passwords in Python 2 and Python 3? Securely?

Tags: python, python-3.x, security, random, cryptography

Here on Stackoverflow exist at least one post related to this topic: [Generate password in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854692/generate-password-in-python)

You can find that this topic found some critics even in PEP. It's mentioned here: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0506/

So, how to generate random passwords in Python 2 and Python 3 properly and securely?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate password in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854692/generate-password-in-python)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Python 2

As you may know, the `random` module in Python 2 use insecure pseudo-random numbers generator. This is stated clearly in the warning on the official documentation page: "The pseudo-random generators of this module should not be used for security purposes."

The `random` module is insecure, because its' internals, that rely on the algorithms (Mersenne Twister algorithm) seeded by the current time on host. Despite having good statistical characteristics of output, the output of such algorithms is highly predictable and vulnerable to Random Numbers Generators Attacks. If you don't believe to security professionals, check out this popular post: https://jazzy.id.au/2010/09/22/cracking_random_number_generators_part_3.html

The official documentation on Python 2 recommends to use `os.urandom` function and `SystemRandom` class, because they use more secure random numbers source provided by operating system.

Operating system generate pseudo-random numbers using the data from multiple sources, most of them are very unpredictable and having high entropy. `os.urandom` on Linux uses output from `/dev/urandom` device. You may check the official kernel documentation for details about `/dev/urandom` and it's differences to `/dev/random`. Also, if you use hardware random number generator, is it possible to use it as `/dev/random`.

The answer on this question in Python 2 may look like this:

```
import os

def gen_password(length=8, charset="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&*()"):
    random_bytes = os.urandom(length)
    len_charset = len(charset)
    indices = [int(len_charset * (ord(byte) / 256.0)) for byte in random_bytes]
    return "".join([charset[index] for index in indices])
```

### Python 3

The latest Python 3.6 has a module called `secrets`. It is proposed in [corresponding PEP-0506 by Steven D'Aprano](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0506/). The purpose of this module is to provide "secure by default" cryptographic primitives suitable for modern applications and for "crypto-naive" users. Also it provides clean and straightforward API for cryptographic stuff.

Consider the following implementation of generating random passwords in Python 3.

```
import secrets

def gen_password(length=8, charset="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&*()"):
    return "".join([secrets.choice(charset) for _ in range(0, length)])
```

Comment: On Python 2, you can also use `SystemRandom`, which uses `urandom` behind the scenes, but exposes a `.choice()` method so you can write a one-liner like the Python 3 example. https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.SystemRandom

Comment: Also, for both Python 2 and 3, `.join()` can be called with a generator expression  instead of a list. The syntax will be a little cleaner, and the code will run faster: `"".join(secrets.choice(charset) for _ in range(length))`