# password generator code using python giving wrong output. Sometimes digit is missing and sometimes special character is missing

Tags: python-2.7

```
import random
import string

password1=''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits `+"@!#%^&*()") for _ in range(7))
password=random.choice(string.ascii_letters) + password1

print password
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate password in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854692/generate-password-in-python)

Comment: It's a `random.choice`.  What did you expect?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: my expected output should be of length 8 and contains upper case, lower case, digit and specified special characters