# Making a password generator with specfic rules in python

Tags: python

I am trying to make a password generator that takes the 2nd and 3rd letter of the users first, middle and last name, and their favourite colour and phone number and makes a password.

Example:

Bobby

Alexander

Jones

Blue

416-666-6666

Will make the password obleonlu16

Now I am relatively new to python. I am in the learning process and when I saw this challenge, I didn't even know where to start. I need help starting this.

Thanks in advance for your replies!

So far I have this:

```
#Get the info needed
print("What is your first name?")
fname = input()
print("What is your middle name?")
mname = input()
print("What is your last name?")
lname = input()
print("What is your favourite colour?")
favcolour = input()
print("Finally, what's your phone number?")
phnum = input()
```

Comment: I think your question is too broad. There are tons of possibile combinations using those "ingredients", any could be good. You should think more about the logic, the way in which you want to combine the ingredients and try to write your code by yourself. If you then have a more specific problem, you can ask here.

Comment: Creating any password in a systematic way is bad practice and you should not dot that. It will severely reduce your users security. There are better ways to create passwords. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39596292/6018688 for a way to make good passwords and read some background here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diceware and here https://www.troyhunt.com/tag/passwords/

Comment: What I really need help is in actually taking the 2nd and 3rd letters of whatever the user inputs into the program. Could you help with that?

Comment: Do you know how to ask the user for input? If so, at least add that in your question, from there we can help. But you will hardly find somebody who writes code for you from scratch. Stackoverflow is not a writing code service.

Comment: Just edited in what I have so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
input_name = input('name:')
input_color = input('color:')
input_phone_number = input('phone number:')
name_list = input_name.split()
color_list = input_color.split()
phone_list = input_phone_number.split()

result = []
for target_list in (name_list, color_list, phone_list):
    [result.append(target[1:3]) for target in target_list]

#print(f"result:{''.join(result)}")  # In python 3.6 or above, you can use `f-string`
print('result:{}'.format(''.join(result)))
```

**demo**

```
name:Bobby Alexander Jones
color:Blue
phone number:416-666-6666
result:obleonlu16
```