# How to generate random password in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, passwords

I want to use `python3` to generate random password to encrypt my files, The random password created should have following restriction

1. Minimum length should be 12
2. Must contain one uppercase letter.
3. Must contain one lowercase letter.
4. Must contain one digit.
5. Must contain one special character.

Actually I don't know much about generating random things in `python` with restrictions so I don't have any code to show here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate password in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854692/generate-password-in-python)

Comment: @OliverF no sir it is not helpful as the answer there are not considering special character in their random generation.

Comment: Ok, well my answer should help.

Comment: The dupe covers what you need. Simply add more code to include special characters. You can create 1 random upper, 1 random lower, 1 random digit, 1 random special and 8 other random ones out of all of them, combine those 12 and shuffle them to make them random positioned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can choose a character from a list with the python `secrets` library. Here is an example:

```
import string
import secrets

symbols = ['*', '%', '£'] # Can add more

password = ""
for _ in range(9):
    password += secrets.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
password += secrets.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)
password += secrets.choice(string.digits)
password += secrets.choice(symbols)
print(password)
```

Comment: you should NOT use the `random` module, it's pseudo-randomness is fine for testing but INCREDIBLY weak for this purpose.  Use the built-in `secrets` module instead

Comment: Thanks for this security clarification, I've fixed my answer.

Comment: A comfortable alternative to defining a *symbols* list is to use ```string.punctuation``` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'm relatively new to python and stackoverflow but here's my shot at your problem:

```
import string
import random


def password_generator(length):
    """ Function that generates a password given a length """

    uppercase_loc = random.randint(1,4)  # random location of lowercase
    symbol_loc = random.randint(5, 6)  # random location of symbols
    lowercase_loc = random.randint(7,12)  # random location of uppercase

    password = ''  # empty string for password

    pool = string.ascii_letters + string.punctuation  # the selection of characters used

    for i in range(length):

        if i == uppercase_loc:   # this is to ensure there is at least one uppercase
            password += random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)

        elif i == lowercase_loc:  # this is to ensure there is at least one uppercase
            password += random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)

        elif i == symbol_loc:  # this is to ensure there is at least one symbol
            password += random.choice(string.punctuation)

        else:  # adds a random character from pool
            password += random.choice(pool)

    return password  # returns the string

print(password_generator(12))
```

I imported two modules, one being 'string', which gives me access to strings with all the characters I need. The other being 'random', which allows me to generate random numbers and pick a random character from a string.

Using random.randint(a, b) I could generate random locations for uppercase, lowercase, and punctuation characters, to ensure that there would be at least one of each.

The only modification I made is that I made it that you can generate a password of any length as long as you input said length into the function.

Here is an example of an output:
L"mJ{~xcL[%M

Comment: you should NOT use the `random` module, it's pseudo-randomness is fine for testing but INCREDIBLY weak for this purpose.  Use the built-in `secrets` module instead

Answer (score 0):

you can generate random bits, convert them to an integer, clamp them so it doesn't pick weird characters and convert them to char

```
 import random
 
  passwrd = ''
  length = 12
  for _ in range(length):
      bits = random.getrandbits(8)
      num = (int('{0:b}'.format(bits),2) + 33) % 127
      passwrd+= chr(num)
```

then you can check if your conditions are satisfied.

Comment: you should NOT use the `random` module, it's pseudo-randomness is fine for testing but INCREDIBLY weak for this purpose.  Use the built-in `secrets` module instead

Answer (score 0):

Below code doing exactly what I asked for but I am marking @OliverF code as the solution to this problem as his code is also working fine and posted before of my own answer.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#import the necessary modules!
import random
import string

length = random.randint(12,25)
lower = string.ascii_lowercase
upper = string.ascii_uppercase
num = string.digits
symbols = string.punctuation
    
all = lower + upper + num + symbols

temp = random.sample(all,length)

password = "".join(temp)

print(password)
```

Comment: you should NOT use the `random` module, it's pseudo-randomness is fine for testing but INCREDIBLY weak for this purpose.  Use the built-in `secrets` module instead