# How to make a Password Generator from User using list?

Tags: python, list, loops

I am trying to create a random password generator in python .

How do I select like 3 or 4 or 5 random number from a list using user.

For example :

```
numbers = ['0','1','2','3,','4','5','6','7','8',9']

numbers_in = int(input('how many numbers would you love to be in your password:').
```

If i choose 4 as a user how will get four random numbers from a list like 4791

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate password in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854692/generate-password-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
>>> from random import choice
>>> from string import digits
>>> N = int(input('How many numbers would you love to be in your password: '))
How many numbers would you love to be in your password: 4
>>> "".join(choice(digits) for _ in range(N))
'1786'
```

Shorter version of the last statement provided by @furas in comments:

```
"".join(choices(digits, k=N))
```

Comment: You don't need a list. ```join``` takes in an iterable. ```"".join(choice(digits) for _ in range(5))```

Comment: @Sujay, thanks, your improvement is added :)

Comment: shorter `choices(digits, k=N)` - (with char `s` in word `choices`)

Comment: @furas, nice! I didn't know this :)