# How do I begin the process of generating the user another password?

Tags: python, loops

I am new to Python (2 wks.) and outside of class have been working on a random password generator.
I have made the password generator; however, I'm not really sure how to begin the process of generating another password for the user. So far, I have tried creating a loop but got lost quickly. My best guess as to what I'm doing wrong is that I just don't understand loops very well and that creating a loop will solve my problem.

```py
# This greets the user
print('Hello, Welcome to this random password generator')

# This asks the user for the length of the password
length = int(input('\nEnter the length of the password you would like to generate: '))

# This defines data for the string module
lower = string.ascii_lowercase
upper = string.ascii_uppercase
number = string.digits

# This combines the data
all = lower + upper + number

# This allows us to randomize the data collected
temp = random.sample(all, length)

# This generates the password
password = "".join(temp)

# This will generate a password of up to 94 characters
print(password)

# This prompts the user to generate another password
next_generation = input("Would you like to generate another password? (yes/no): ")
```

Comment: Please don't post code as image, copy and paste the code within the post itself.

Comment: Just figured out how to do this, thanks for the tip!

Comment: It's not really clear where or how you want to use a loop in your code. However, generating passwords can be done easily with premade modules. Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854692/generate-password-in-python) help?

Comment: @Lucas thanks for the help! I didn't think you could do it simpler. Guess I still have a lot to learn. As for the loop I'm not really sure whether or not it's the best course of action. I simply just want to generate another password for the user after it prints the initial password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random
import string

while True:
    length = int(input("Enter password length: "))

    lower = string.ascii_lowercase
    upper = string.ascii_uppercase
    number = string.digits

    all = lower+upper+number
    temp = random.sample(all,length)
    password = ''.join(temp)
    print(password)

    # **** This block asks user whether to create another password ****
    # If Yes, code loops back to the beginning and does it again
    # If No, code stops.
    another = input("Generate another password? Y/N: ").capitalize().strip()
    if another == 'Y':
        another = True
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You indeed need to use a loop and store data in an array or print it in the loop. This article might be of help as it explains:
[How to use loops to keep program running](http://introtopython.org/while_input.html#Using-while-loops-to-keep-your-programs-running)

I assume that you want your program to keep asking for new password each time and the number of passwords is not fixed. Otherwise you would use `for loop`.

Comment: thanks! I will be sure to read that article.